# XML/Json with square bracket format

Tags: c#, xml, json, api, parsing

I am looking into using the TVRage Api, and the show info Search API comes back in standard XML format.

> http://services.tvrage.com/feeds/search.php?show=buffy

However, the Schedule "API" comes back in a weird Square-Bracket format. It looks like XML, but doesn't encapsulate elements the same way standard XML would do.

> http://services.tvrage.com/tools/quickschedule.php

For instance, in XML you could expect the following:

```
<Day>
  <Date>Monday, 23 Sep 2013</Date>
  <Time>05:00pm</Time>
  <Show>MBC Sports Tonight</Show>
</Day>
```

But instead it is coming back in the following format:

```
[DAY]Monday, 23 Sep 2013[/DAY]
[TIME]05:00 pm[/TIME]
[SHOW]NBC Sports Tonight[/SHOW]
[TIME]05:30 pm[/TIME]
[SHOW]Pro Football Talk[/SHOW]
[DAY]Monday, 24 Sep 2013[/DAY]
[TIME]06:00 pm[/TIME]
[SHOW]NBC Sports Tomorrow[/SHOW]
```

Does anyone know what this format is, and if there is a standard way to convert it into objects in C# or if I need to create my own parser to handle it.

It seems weird that they would have their search feeds in standard XML and have their schedule in something that is not a standard format.

So if anyone can enlighten me on this output, I would greatly appreciate it.

Cheers,
Kris

Comment: Seems proprietary to me.

Comment: That's seriously silly if they have chosen that. The search one is so neatly layed out in standard format.

Comment: Yup this looks proprietary, you most likely have to code some parsing yourself

Comment: If only it was acceptable to complain about free services ;)

Cool, thanks guys. I will start on creating a custom parser.

Comment: If there's an API, is there any documentation? It's possible that it's XML with different brackets, but unlikely. If it IS, though, you can fix it with a few `String.Replace` calls

Comment: @valverij That won't be possible. Take a close look at the data, `[/DAY]` would have to be at the bottom for starters. It needs sequential parsing.

Comment: valverij - I thought about that. However, XML would use a tree structure. This seems to use a line-by-line formatting. So, for instance, the "SHOW" is after the "TIME", which is after the "DAY". They aren't inside the structure. Therefore, seem to me, it won't work as XML. (EDIT: What Stijn said)

Answer (score 2):

I would like to answer this.

I created a nifty string extension that took in the string with [] formatting, and returned a string containing the results in a custom-created, well-structured XML document.

I then created a C# class which mimicked the structure I had just created.

I created another string extension that took in XML and returned a strongly typed object of T that matches (my C# class I had created).

I then had a look again on the TVRage website, because I wanted to see what parameters I could call this URL with.

...

Then I noticed alongside this "Schedule" API there was a "FULL Schedule" link... This was the same as the Schedule link I was using, except already in XML format.

**Doh**.

If anyone was as silly as me, please find the correct URL to use:

> http://services.tvrage.com/feeds/fullschedule.php

Have a good day,
Kris

Comment: Usually when you see a proprietary format then it's done for a very specific use case.  The first one you posted looks as if it's for a dumb app that writes the output in blocks.  Glad to here you found the good data though.

Comment: To be fair on you, whether a schedule was "full" or "quick", changing the data format between the two seems asinine.